# Python, Flask: show categories list of current user in Flaskform

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am new to Python and need help with my Flask app. I need to create a form for adding new product. I use FlaskForm and SQLAlchemy with SQlite database. In this form I want to show categories list of current seller.

**Problem #1.**
Here is my code for database models:

```
class seller(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "sellers"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    key = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Shop {}>'.format(self.name)

class productCategory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "productCategories"
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sellerId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sellers.id'))
    parentCategoryId = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)

    seller = relationship('seller')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Product Category {}>'.format(self.name)
```

Here is my code for building a form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, IntegerField, SelectField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from wtforms.validators import NumberRange
from app import db, app

class createProductForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self, categories):
        self.categories = categories

    prodSku = StringField('Артикул', validators=[DataRequired()])
    prodName = StringField('Название', validators=[DataRequired()])
    prodCategory = SelectField('Категория', choices=categories, validators=[DataRequired()])
    prodLength = IntegerField('Длина упаковки (см)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999)])
    prodWidth = IntegerField('Ширина упаковки (см)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999)])
    prodThick = IntegerField('Толщина упаковки (см)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999)])
    prodWeight = IntegerField('Вес (гр)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=999999)])
    purchasePrice = IntegerField('Закупочная цена (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999999)])
    submit = SubmitField('Создать')
```

When running my app I get *"categories" is not defined* error. Where am I wrong?

**Problem #2:**
Here is my code for url processing:

```
@app.route('/create-product', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def createProduct():
    with app.app_context():
        categories = db.session.query(productCategory).filter(productCategory.seller.key == 'TEST').all()

    '''
    Here will be the code that creates categoriesList in format: ([], [], [])
    '''

    form = createProductForm(categoriesList)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        currentProduct = product()
        currentProduct.sku = form.prodSku.data
        currentProduct.name = form.prodName.data
        currentProduct.category = form.prodCategory.data
        currentProduct.length = form.prodLength.data
        currentProduct.width = form.prodWidth.data
        currentProduct.thick = form.prodThick.data
        currentProduct.weight = form.prodWeight.data
        currentProduct.purchasePrice = form.purchasePrice.data
        db.session.add(currentProduct)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Новый товар создан')
        return redirect('/index')
    return render_template('create-product.html', title='Создание товара', form=form, categoties = categories)
```

I expect to get categories of current seller by filtering by sellers key ('TEST'). But after running this code the categories variable is empty. Where am I wrong?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows you a way to dynamically create a form in which a category can be selected based on the seller's specified key attribute.

Instead of extending the form, it is created in a factory method, adding input fields as usual. An input field of type [`QuerySelectField`](https://wtforms-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wtforms_sqlalchemy/#wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField) is used to make the categories available for selection. The database query that is passed to the field uses a JOIN statement in which the category is queried using the referenced ForeignKey, which points to the seller's ID. Filtering is done based on the seller’s key attribute.

If the form is sent and the information is valid, the product can be created. Due to the naming of the attributes, it is possible to use [`Form.populate_obj(obj)`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form.populate_obj) to transfer the form data to the newly created object.

```py
'''
% pip install flask flask-sqlalchemy flask-wtf wtforms-sqlalchemy
'''

from flask import (
    Flask, 
    redirect, 
    render_template, 
    request, 
    url_for
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
import random 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='your secret here', 
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///example.db', 
)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Seller(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sellers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    key = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)

class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)
    # ...

    seller_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sellers.id'))
    seller = db.relationship('Seller')

class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...
    
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    category = db.relationship('Category')

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    sellers = [Seller(
            key=f'Test-{i}',
            name=f'Unknown Tester {i}'
        ) for i in range(1, 5)
    ]
    db.session.add_all(sellers)
    db.session.commit()

    categories = [
        Category(
            seller=random.choice(sellers), 
            name=f'Category-{i}'
        ) for i in range(1,17)
    ]
    db.session.add_all(categories)
    db.session.commit()

def make_create_product_form(seller_key):
    class CreateProductForm(FlaskForm):
        category = QuerySelectField('Category', 
            query_factory=lambda: db.session.execute(
                db.select(Category)
                    .join(Seller, Seller.id == Category.seller_id)
                    .where(Seller.key == seller_key)).scalars(), 
            get_label='name'
        )
        # ...
    return CreateProductForm

# ...

@app.route('/create-product', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_product():
    form = make_create_product_form('Test-1')(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        product = Product()
        form.populate_obj(product)
        db.session.add(product)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('create_product.html', **locals())
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Create Product</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div>
            {{ form.category.label() }}
            {{ form.category() }}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```